# C++ track thread completion

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, threadpool

I have a vector of 25 elements and I want to process 5 elements concurrently in different threads
But at any time I don't want to create more than 5 thread i.e in one particular time 5 elements will be processed( 0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, 20-24)

The code is as follows

```
void test(vector<string> &input){

vector<std::thread> threads;  
for(int i=0; i<25;++i){
  threads.push_back(std::thread(func, input, i)); //func is a function called by the thread which accepts 2 argument vector<string> and int
  if(threads.size()==5){
    for (auto &th : threads) {
      th.join();
    }
    threads.clear();
  }
}
```

Here the code will wait till all the 5 thread are completed and then will process for next set

Is there a way to check if any thread gets completed, then a new thread is created but the total count of threads should be <= 5

Comment: Take a look at std::future. You can start push back std::future objects into the vector, launching threads via calls to std::async. You can wait short amounts of time on a std::future object in order to test whether the processing is done.

Comment: Also, in case this is not just a programming exercise; Consider using OpenMP, since this problem is very easy to solve using that (just apply a #pragma in front of your for loop and you're done)

Comment: Fairly simple job scheduler implementation. Worker threads, before existing, record their upcoming demise in a shared queue. Parent thread drains the queue, and formally `join()`s each terminated thread. Parent thread easily tracks how many worker threads are running, and can launch the next one as soon as the previous worker thread terminates.

Comment: Don't re-create threads every time, that's expensive. Instead use a thread pool and submit "tasks" to the pool. See also std::packaged_task.